# Countvectorizer with foreign symbols gives swapped key-values in vocabulary dictionary

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining

I'm using a `CountVectorizer`:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import pandas as pd
series = pd.Series(["abc", "aaa"])
CountVectorizer(analyzer='char').fit(series).vocabulary_
```

This results in a vocabulary with the letters as keys and the index in the vocabulary as values:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
```

Now let's add some foreign (arab?) characters:

```
series = pd.Series(["d'ا'ر'م'ی'ن'abc", "aaa"])
CountVectorizer(analyzer='char').fit(series).vocabulary_

{'d': 4,
 "'": 0,
 'ا': 5,
 'ر': 6,
 'م': 7,
 'ی': 9,
 'ن': 8,
 'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 3}
```

See how the keys and values are swapped for the foreign characters, so the character and the index are swapped. What's happening? It looks like it's due to the fact that in some languages people read from right to left? Is this part of the behaviour of Python dictionaries?

Comment: I am getting  this `{'d': 4, "'": 0, 'ا': 5, 'ر': 6, 'م': 7, 'ی': 9, 'ن': 8, 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}` in visual studio code. Probably the bug could be because of editor.

Comment: Output looks quite similar. I have it in both Jupyter and PyCharm

Answer (score 1):

The keys and values are no actually swapped. It is just a visual "bug" when printing the dictionary.

When you define a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {'d': 4,
 "'": 0,
 'ا': 5,
 'ر': 6,
 'م': 7,
 'ی': 9,
 'ن': 8,
 'a': 1,
 'b': 2,
 'c': 3}
```

You can still access the value of one of the elements with the corresponding key:

```
dict['م']
```

Which gives you the expected result of:

> 7

Comment: Makes sense. Any clue why this visual "bug" is happening?

Comment: Couldn't really tell you. But [this](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3846) could be relevant. It seems to be quite complicated :)